# l3backend.sty not found

Tags: r, latex, pdfbox

Where can i find the latex file l3backend.sty. I installed l3backend package via Miktex but still the file is not there. I get error message l3backend.sty not found Please anyone help. I am stuck

Comment: Please make a [mre]. The l3backend package consists of .def files.

Comment: How is this related to pdfbox?

Comment: I get same error: Here's a minimum working example. 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3backend}
\usepackage{tasks}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}
\end{tasks}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\begin{enumerate}
\item dolor sit amet?
\item laboris nisi!
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no `l3backend.sty`. Whether your tex file file was calling `l3backend.sty` you can skip by `\expandafter`. Try in your preamble

```
\expandafter\def\csname
ver@l3backend.sty\endcsname{}
```